# Inequality of matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Suppose that we have four matrices $Y, A, B, C$. We have $Y = ABC$. The power of $Y$ is $Y^{i} = (ABC)^{i} $.

1. By using the submultiplicative property of matrix norm,
   $\| Y^{i}\| \le \| A\|^{i}  \| B\|^{i}  \|C \|^{i} $ can be easily proved.
2. However, is the relation  $\| Y^{i}\| \le \| A^{i}\|  \| B^{i}\|  \|C^{i} \| $ holds? Can anybody give the proof?

Answer (score 2):

This inequality does not hold: if one of those matrices is nilpotent, then $Y^i$ might not be null, but the rhs of the inequality is zero.

Take, e.g., $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$, $B=I_2$, $C=A^T$. Then $Y^i= \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ but $A^i=C^i=0$ for $i\ge 2$.

Comment: If those matrices are not nilpotent, what will be the result? For example, A and C are adjacent matrices (with columns and rows adding up to one), B is any square matrix.